# WPF - cascading ComboBoxes, dependent ones don't update

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, xaml, combobox

I have three ComboBoxes such that C's items list is dependent on the selected item in B and B's items list is dependent on the selected item in A.  I have `ObservableCollection`s of particular classes for the `ItemsSource` on each ComboBox, and I want the `Name` property of the selected item to be pushed to a property in another class.  For example:

```
ObservableCollection<AClass> Items
=> ItemsSource of cbo_A ComboBox
```

And `selectedInstanceOfAClass.Name` should be pushed to `Data.AClassName` property.  The problem I have is that when I choose a value in the A ComboBox the first time, the B ComboBox gets the appropriate items based on the selected item in A, as expected.  Same for when I select an item in B for the first time--C gets the right items.  However, when I choose a different value in A, the items in B get updated but the selected value of B stays the same, and when I try to select a new value in B from its new items, the selection doesn't change--it stays the same selected value as what I initially selected in B.

Here's the XAML I have right now:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cbo_A"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Lists.AItems, Mode=OneWay}"
    DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="Name"
    SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Data.AClassName, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,
        Mode=OneWayToSource}" />

<ComboBox x:Name="cbo_B"
    ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=cbo_A, Path=SelectedItem.BItems, Mode=OneWay}"
    SelectedValuePath="Name" DisplayMemberPath="Name"
    SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Data.BClassName, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,
        Mode=OneWayToSource}"/>

<ComboBox x:Name="cbo_C"
    ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=cbo_B, Path=SelectedItem.CItems, Mode=OneWay}"
    SelectedValuePath="Name" DisplayMemberPath="Name"
    SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Data.CClassName, Mode=OneWayToSource,
        ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />
```

What is causing the weird behavior with the selected value not updating even when I explicitly click the ComboBox and try to change the value?

**Edit:** when debugging and I had a `SelectionChanged` handler on `cbo_A` and another on `cbo_B`, I entered the `cbo_B` handler before the `cbo_A` one, so the selected item from B's perspective was still the old item, because A had not been updated yet.  :/

**Edit 2:** if I flip the order of my ComboBoxes in XAML, suggested by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606343/wpf-2-combobox-binding-problem), such that C comes before B comes before A, I enter A's handler first.  When I then enter the handler for `cbo_B`, the `SelectedItem` property shows the old value (previously selected, before I chose a new value in `cbo_A`), even though I clicked a value from the new list of items showing up in the ComboBox.

**Edit 3:** I'm trying a version of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005146/2-or-more-comboboxes-dependent-on-each-other/3005395#3005395) and getting the same problem:  I see new values in ComboBox B upon changing the selected value of ComboBox A, but I cannot change the selected value in B after I've already set it once.  I'm beginning to think I've got something else going awry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow.  So, don't go quickly implementing a bunch of `IEquatable<T>` `Equals` methods for new classes, because you may end up doing what I did:

```
if (ReferenceEquals(this, other))
{
    return false;  // Say what??
}
```

Sigh.  I got my ComboBoxes to work by:

- Correcting my `BClass.Equals(BClass other)` method;
- Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005146/2-or-more-comboboxes-dependent-on-each-other/3005395#3005395) about having another view model class with different properties like `SelectedAItem` and `AItems`; and
- Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606343/wpf-2-combobox-binding-problem/606418#606418) about putting my XAML declarations in a different order so `cbo_C` comes before `cbo_B` and `cbo_B` comes before `cbo_A`.

I may try simplifying things and see what parts are absolutely necessary for my ComboBoxes.